# Python class not working

Tags: python, class

How can i modify a copy of a class without the original class being changed as well?

when i have a class like this:

```
class enemymob:
    def __init__(self, name, level, damage, health, maxhealth, armour):
        self.name = name 
        self.level = level
        self.damage = damage
        self.health = health
        self.maxhealth = maxhealth
        self.armour = armour

Goblin = enemymob("Goblin", 1, 10, 50, 50, 5)
```

and then i set enemy = Goblin:

```
enemy = Goblin
```

when i modify the value of the enemy, it also changes the value of the instance goblin as well. But for my code i need the instance Goblin's values to stay the same, and only change the value for it's copy, the enemy. How can i do that?

```
enemy.damage += 100
print(enemy.damage)
print(Goblin.damage)

110                                                                                                                                                                                                 
110                                                                                                                                                                                                 


Process exited with code: 0
```

Comment: Maybe you want to instantiate two new objects instead of making a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `enemy = Goblin` makes the `enemy` variable point to the same instance as the `Goblin` variable. If you want a new instance you can manipulate independently, you'd have to copy it, e.g., by using the `copy` module:

```
import copy
enemy = copy.copy(Goblin)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `deepcopy` to make the copy of the object -

```
from copy import deepcopy

enemy = deepcopy(Goblin)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Goblin` and `enemy` are pointing to the same thing. When you do `Goblin = enemymob("Goblin", 1, 10, 50, 50, 5)` followed by `enemy = Goblin` both `enemy` and `Goblin` will end up pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you set both your variables, enemy and Goblin to the same object. Create two object like that:

```
enemy = enemymob("enemy", 1, 10, 50, 50, 5)
Goblin = enemymob("Goblin", 1, 10, 50, 50, 5)
```